# create a video from stills playable on win7 powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, video-conversion, video-encoding

with respect to image size H x W, and to total size of the video file, **and what type of video file** what is the *best* method of taking a bunch of still images to a smooth playable video file **that will work well in powerpoint for a briefing ?**

so far

- i have 720 .tiff files making up one rotation, every 1/2° but i can reduce to 180 stills
- on windows 7 use MakeDVI.exe to create an avi file

  - there's Microsoft RLE, Intel iYUV, fully uncompressed; these create > GB file that does not play
  - there's Microsoft Video 1 which seems to work most reliably creating > 100MB avi
  - there's Cinepak codec by Radius
  - also get to choose frames per second
- depending on the AVI compression used, may or may not play in windows media player in windows 7
- having trouble every which way getting avi to play smoothly when embedded in power point
- need to stay within powerpoint and windows media player for compatibility and portability between work environments (win 7/8/10)

Do I need to convert the 5MB each .tiff files (x720) to .jpg or something first, where each .jpg file is in KB size?

and with 720 frames @ 30fps = 24 seconds for 1 rotation, I would also like ability to play faster like 1 rotation in 3 seconds or slow down to 1 rotation in 24 seconds.

What video format should I end up going for to get smoothest playback within microsoft powerpoint and be reliably portable between displaying computers (has or does not have graphics card, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i '*.tiff' -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Explanation (note that the order of the options is important):

- `-framerate` sets the playback speed - adjust as necessary
- `-pattern_type glob` tells ffmpeg that you want it to interpret `*` as wildcard in the filename.
- `-c:v libx264` uses `h264` as the video format. This codec should be built in with most machines and in my experience is the least problematic codec for videos in powerpoint.
- `-crf 22` set the quality factor to 22. The [ffmpeg h264 documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) states:

> The range of the CRF scale is 0–51, where 0 is lossless, 23 is the
>   default, and 51 is worst quality possible. A lower value generally
>   leads to higher quality, and a subjectively sane range is 17–28.
>   Consider 17 or 18 to be visually lossless or nearly so.

- `-pix_fmt yuv420p` make sure to convert the colors of the input images to a format that the codec can handle
- `out.mp4` the name of the output file. Make sure it ends in `mp4` not `avi` as mp4 is a more modern and more portable video file format.

In case the order of the files gets mixed up, rename them (for example with [mucommander](https://www.mucommander.com/)) to have four-digit numbers with leading zeros in the right sequence in the filename and then run this command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i img%04d.tiff -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Note that h264 expects your image to have an even number of pixels in each dimension (i.e. 640x480 not 641x479) if that is not the case, you can use [ffmpegs cropping filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -pattern_type glob -i img%03d.tiff -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

See also this [great answer on stackoverflow by khan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg/24966617#24966617) and [the official ffmpeg documentation for creating video slideshows](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow)